# Unable to access BtSync process website running on RaspBerry Pi Model B+

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

I currently have a Raspberry Pi Model B+ with Raspbian OS installed.
Recently, I have tried to install BitTorrent Sync on my raspberry pi and after following [this tutorial,](http://jack.minardi.org/raspberry_pi/replace-dropbox-with-bittorrent-sync-and-a-raspberry-pi/) I managed to get

> BitTorrent Sync forked to background. pid = 2254. default port = 8888

after executing

> ./btsync

This shows that  BtSync is successfully running. But the problem is, after going on my computer and navigating to [MyRpiIP]:8888/gui, I get the "This webpage is not available" error by Chrome.

Is there any way I can fix this? The Raspberry pi is on the same network as me.

Comment: Can you ping or SSH into the Pi? If not, then my guess would be that the Pi is having issues with the 8888 port and your router. Do you have anything else running on the Pi that is serving web content? Also, try just going to [raspberrypiIP]:8888 and see if that does anything.

Comment: I can successfully ping and SSH to the pi. There are no other web services running.  I tried accessing [raspberrypiIP]:8888 but that doesn't work. It's strange, I have had other services work 100%. Is there a way to change the port of the BTSync Service?

Comment: Just a quick update.  Chrome error code is ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually have that port open. Can you run ` netstat -pln` and give me the output? Also, after doing that, try running `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 0 -j ACCEPT` then `sudo iptable-save` and seeing if it works.

Comment: Can you try to "wget 127.0.0.1:8888/gui" and see if an html file appears in the current directory?

Comment: Firstly, I would like to thank everyone who participated in this thread. I managed to fix the problem by installing a localhost tunnel called  [ngrok](http://ngrok.com). So far, it is doing the job perfectly. Thank you all  for commenting in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
./btsync --webui.listen 0.0.0.0:8888
```